# Multiple Profile Account Creation (Concrete5)

Tags: content-management-system, xlsx, accounts

Alright so I am working on a site and it requires some 100 names of people to create an account for. We are using the latest version of Concrete5(c5 is a pain). I have a template for the profile page and all i need to do is edit in the boxes of all the people. is their any easier way than adding them all in manually. We are open to the option of not using c5 for the profile creation portion.  I have never had to do something like this so if anyone has any clue on how this could be completed faster please give me some feedback

also all the people i need to add profiles for are in a custom made excel sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fairly easy option would be to create a csv file of the contacts, upload that csv to your C5 directory and then create a single page to import the contacts.

The single page shows nothing only reads the csv file and create new users using the following function: `$newUserInfoObject = UserInfo::add($data);`

Where $data is an array that can contain

- uName - the username. Required.
- uEmail - Email address. Required.
- uPassword - the non-encrypted password.
- uIsValidated - Whether the email address has been validated. If not
  specified, -1 will be saved.
- uIsFullRecord -   Set to 1 unless set in the array to 0.

source: [C5 users](http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/permissions/users/)
(you should check if the username already exists, and if so add an incrementing integer to the username)

After you coded the single page to read the csv and added it in the dashboard (back-end), you go to the page once and your contacts will be imported.
How to create a single page: [C5 single pages](http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/pages/single-pages/)

After importing the data, delete the single page from the system, so no one else can accidently import the same contacts again.